# How to integrate Palantir Foundry with Amazon S3 or HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

Within Palantir Foundry platform, I am working in Data integration. I need some help as I am new to Palantir software. Is there any documents, white-papers, links or tutorials on this topic?

How do I integrate data from another source, for example Amazon S3 or HDFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To integrate data from another Platform you'll need a source and a sync in data connection. You'll need to have platform permissions to create these, not all users can since it can involve the organisation data governance policies.

Assuming you don't have a source with a valid configuration for S3. You'll need to create one. On Data Connection, click "Sources" and then click "New Source". You can then do this in two ways:

- Use prebuilt S3 source: Click `File System` in the new `New Source` drop down and follow the wizard steps
- Use a custom connector such as magritte-rest: Click `Custom` in the same dropdown.

For the magritte-rest:

- Select either one of the available agents, or Cloud ingest depending on your preferences
- Give it a name and save it into a folder.
- Add configuration like:

```
type: magritte-rest
url: 'https://foobar.organization.s3.amazonaws.com'
```

Now to create the Sync, use a configuration similar to this:

```
type: rest-source-adapter
method: GET
path: the/path/in/s3/yourdata
outputFileType: csv
```

Other output file types are also supported (`json`, `zip`, ...)

Answer (score 6):

Palantir usually makes available on the customer company intranet a Q&A forum to help developers and address issues.

Moreover they provide also on-site support and there is on Foundry workspace home page a section called Training & learning, providing examples and tutorial to get started.